# Netflix Sliverlight update

Tags: moonlight, netflix

So I found away to install netflix on my Ubuntu 12.10 OS a while back but now it requires a higher version of silverlight and I tried moonlight and reinstalling it the same way but it doest seem to work anyone have this problem and know how to fix it? ( this is the way i installed it http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/how-to-get-netflix-streaming-on-ubuntu-1210/4019 )

Comment: Moonlight is no longer developed.  If this update of Netflix broke something, then you'll have to wait for everything to catch up so you can work around the current block, as it currently stands i am assuming no updates to the software referenced exist to work around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. From the terminal execute this command.

   `rm -Rf ~/.wine-browser`
2. Start netflix, it will reinstall the .wine-browser folder againg, when you see netflix login screen CLOSED.
3. Execute the program Silverlight.Configuration.exe that is on folder /.wine-browser.

   ```
   cd ~/.wine-browser/drive_c/Program*Files/Microsoft*Silverlight/4.1.10329.0
   wine Silverlight.Configuration.exe
   ```
4. On the Playback tab: Uncheck the box that say: Enable download and updates to components required for protected contents playback.
5. Login to your Netflix account and problem fix...

Answer (score 0):

The required SilverLight update stops netflix streaming from working, and we will just have to wait for the awesome programmer Erich Hoover to come with an update to his Netflix-Desktop and/or compholio Wine library version.

There is no way to get around the upgrade/update of Silverlight that Netflix asks for to continue watching. I myself attempted an upgrade of silverlight and then netflix does not even recognize that Silverlight is installed any longer.

There must be some new dependencies which are not necessary on a windows machine, or already present. I have no solution for this. I will take time to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the Mepis forum at the following link:

http://forum.mepiscommunity.org/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=34520&p=316214

I deleted ~/.wine-browser and restarted Netflix-Desktop and all is well again.